# Modificar valor array de una clase VBA Excel

Tags: array, excel, vba

Tengo una clase que, entre otros, tiene la propiedad pcoordenadas con sus correspondiendtes métodos:

```
Private pcoordenadas(0 To 2) As Double  

Public Property Get coordenadas() As Double()
    coordenadas = pcoordenadas    
End Property

Public Property Let coordenadas(coordenadas() As Double)    
    pcoordenadas = coordenadas    
End Property
```

Cuando intento modificar el valor de "pcoordenadas" de la clase me sale un error diciendo: " Error de compilación: No se puede asignar la propiedad sólo de lectura". He probado declarando pcoordenadas como `Variant` y con distintas asignaciones pero ninguna funciona `elementos(i).coordenadas(0) = coor_bloque(0)` / `elementos(i).coordenadas = coor_bloque`. 
Podría alguien echarme una mano ? Un saludo !

Answer (score 0):

Haciendo una clase para manejar datos de SQL Server desde Access traté de hacer algo parecido y no lo logré, en concreto era pasar a la clase varios parámetros y estos a su vez a un procedimiento almacenado. Espero que el código que te paso de ejemplo te sirva para lo que necesitas. Saludos.

```
Private pcoordenadas As Collection
Public Property Get coordenadas() As Collection
Set coordenadas = pcoordenadas
End Property
Public Property Let coordenadas(coordenadas As Collection)
Set pcoordenadas = coordenadas
End Property

Sub x3()
Dim col As New Collection
col.Add 10
col.Add 20
Dim x As Clase
Set x = New Clase
x.coordenadas = col
For Each aa In x.coordenadas
    Debug.Print aa
Next

End Sub
```